# Which mourning laws does an Ashkenazi son follow after his Sefardi mother's death?

Tags: halacha-theory, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mourning-aveilus, ashkenazi

An Ashkenazi son (his father was a Yekke) who mourns after his Sefardi mother - does he follow Ashkenazi Minhagim of Avelut (Kaddish for 11 months exactly for example) of Sefardi?

Comment: Why wouldnt he follow his minhag?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Aveilus obligates the mourner, not the deceased. The nature of the deceased is irrelevant; the mourner would follow his *mesorah* on any differences between Sephardic or Ashkenazic customs.

Comment: בשם הר״ן: אל תטוש תורת אמך. היינו הולך אחר מנהגך.

Comment: THis is a good Svarah, but why not the opposite? The deceased need Kaddishim acc. to his Minhag - seems equally plausible to me.